# continue by sock.recv() when empty python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a thread running that is looking for data from a socket connection.  When it is empty it just sits there as I found it is supposed to, but I would like to pass by this when it is empty.  I found that the select module should be able to do it, but now it just sits at the select line instead. I have tried this below from some research, but like I said, now instead of stopping at the data = sock.recv, it stops at the first line.  Any ideas? Thanks.

```
while True:
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock], [], [])
        if readable:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
        else:
            do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you could have read in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select), `select.select()` takes an optional 4th argument, taking a timeout value.

If the timeout passes without `sock` becoming readable, `readable` is empty.

You can try something like

```
while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock], [], [], 1.0)
    if readable:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
    else:
        print "nothing yet"
```

Comment: readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock], [], [], timeout=1.0)
TypeError: select() takes no keyword arguments - I did try that but get this error

Comment: That means you can't use a keyword argument, just pass the timeout instead: `readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock], [], [], 1.0)`.

Comment: @user3582887 Ok, then I misunderstood that part of the documentation, but you already had the idea to try `select.select([sock], [], [], 1.0)` afterwards, didn't you?

Comment: @SiHa As "the optional `timeout` argument specifies a time-out as a floating point number in seconds", as the doc states, it is unlikely it would do so.

Comment: Thanks all, sorry, didn't have that idea, didn't understand the error, but appreciate all the input.